# Mysql sum count occurrences in multiple columns from another table

Tags: mysql, count

I need to find the sum of occurrences of ids in a join table. The id could be present in two different columns (id_type_1 and id_type_2).

Table types

```
id | name
1  | Test1
2  | Test2
3  | Test3
```

Table products

```
id | name     | id_type_1 | id_type_2
1  | Product1 | 1         | 2
2  | Product2 | 3         | 1
3  | Product3 | 1         | 3
```

I need to get a result like this:

```
Type  | Total
Test1 | 3
Test2 | 1
Test3 | 2
```

Here's my query, but it takes several seconds to execute:

```
SELECT t.name, 
(SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM products p WHERE p.id_type_1 = t.id || p.id_type_2 = t.id) AS total 
FROM types t 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Is there a more effective way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and aggregate:

```
select t.id, t.name,
       sum((t.id = p.id_type_1) + (t.id = p.id_type_2)) Total
from types t inner join products p
on t.id in (p.id_type_1, p.id_type_2)
group by t.id, t.name
```

If there is no case for the `id` to exist in both `id_type_1` and `id_type_2` in the same row then:

```
select t.id, t.name,
       count(*) Total
from types t inner join products p
on t.id in (p.id_type_1, p.id_type_2)
group by t.id, t.name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7efffae8a6772a25b24cd1447aada783).
Results:

```
> id | name  | Total
> -: | :---- | ----:
>  1 | Test1 |     3
>  2 | Test2 |     1
>  3 | Test3 |     2
```